# How do I decide which data mining method/algorithm to choose?

Tags: pyspark, data-mining

My dataset contains values for energy produced each year. I want to basically find out how much renewable energy(Hydro, Nuclear, Solar, Wind) is produced by each country when compared to the total production of energy. Can I use regression or clustering to find this out? I want to use a data mining method/algorithm to do this. Anyone knows how I can proceed?

```
id;Country;Year;IsEstimate;CountryID;TotalDemand;TotalProduction;HydroProduction;NuclearProduction;SolarProduction;WindProduction
1;Afghanistan;2016;False;;5406.1;1076.3;926.6;;;
2;Afghanistan;2015;False;;4752.6;1033.7;889.5;;;
3;Afghanistan;2014;False;;4702.1;1049.3;895.3;;;
4;Afghanistan;2013;False;;4580.5;1022.3;803.9;;;
5;Afghanistan;2012;False;;4038;1022;878;;;
6;Afghanistan;2011;False;;3687;1005;829;;;
7;Afghanistan;2010;False;;2732;892;767;;;
8;Afghanistan;2009;False;;1793;889;775;;;
9;Afghanistan;2008;False;;1568;788;541;;;
10;Afghanistan;2007;False;;1682;950;684;;;
11;Afghanistan;2006;False;;1455;913;646;;;
12;Afghanistan;2005;False;;993;906;671;;;
13;Afghanistan;2004;False;;943;797;565;;;
14;Afghanistan;2003;False;;977;921;647;;;
15;Afghanistan;2002;False;;782.2;722.2;571;;;
16;Afghanistan;2001;False;;745.1;691.1;503.2;;;
17;Afghanistan;2000;False;;741.7;687.7;515.7;;;
18;Afghanistan;1999;False;;739;685;505;;;
19;Afghanistan;1998;False;;719;665;495;;;
20;Afghanistan;1997;False;;728;670;485;;;
21;Afghanistan;1996;False;;743;675;475;;;
22;Afghanistan;1995;False;;753;675;466;;;
23;Afghanistan;1994;False;;770;687;472;;;
24;Afghanistan;1993;False;;780;695;475;;;
25;Afghanistan;1992;False;;789;703;478;;;
26;Afghanistan;1991;False;;945;1015;690;;;
27;Afghanistan;1990;False;;1055;1128;764;;;
28;Albania;2015;False;;7265;5895;5895;;;
29;Albania;2014;False;;7791.43;4724.43;4724.43;;;
30;Albania;2013;False;;9278.53;6956;6956;;;
31;Albania;2012;False;;7263;4725;4725;;;
32;Albania;2011;False;;7187.87;4217.3;4158;;;
33;Albania;2010;False;;6794.28;7744.17;7743.3;;;
34;Albania;2009;False;;6629.26;5231.36;5230.49;;;
35;Albania;2008;False;;6230.23;3796.51;3796.51;;;
36;Albania;2007;False;;5726;2946;2874;;;
37;Albania;2006;False;;6100;5524;5431;;;
38;Albania;2005;False;;5797;5443;5373;;;
39;Albania;2004;False;;5687;5559;5466;;;
40;Albania;2003;False;;6106;5230;5169;;;
41;Albania;2002;False;;5756;3686;3512;;;
42;Albania;2001;False;;5414;3692;3555;;;
43;Albania;2000;False;;5709;4738;4594;;;
44;Albania;1999;False;;5642;5397;5284;;;
45;Albania;1998;False;;5425;5068;4921;;;
46;Albania;1997;False;;5017;5184;5028;;;
47;Albania;1996;False;;5649;5926;5726;;;
48;Albania;1995;False;;4308;4414;4204;;;
49;Albania;1994;False;;3680;3903;3771;;;
50;Albania;1993;False;;3173;3484;3314;;;
51;Albania;1992;False;;2677;3357;3219;;;
52;Albania;1991;False;;2409;3752;3567;;;
53;Albania;1990;False;;3299;3197;2801;;;
54;Algeria;2016;False;;63782;70995;218;;87;29
55;Algeria;2015;False;;62181;68798;145;;58;19
56;Algeria;2014;False;;57502;64242;254;;;
57;Algeria;2013;False;;54928;59890;330;;;
58;Algeria;2012;False;;52595;57397;622;;;
59;Algeria;2011;False;;46540;51224;502;;;
60;Algeria;2010;False;;43162;45734;174;;;
61;Algeria;2009;False;;36336;38501;306;;;
62;Algeria;2008;False;;37827;40236;283;;;
63;Algeria;2007;False;;34455;37196;226;;;
64;Algeria;2006;False;;32766;35226;218;;;
65;Algeria;2005;False;;31129;32875;555;;;
66;Algeria;2004;False;;29587;31250;251;;;
67;Algeria;2003;False;;27367;29571;265;;;
68;Algeria;2002;False;;25542;27647;57;;;
69;Algeria;2001;False;;24460;26624;69;;;
70;Algeria;2000;False;;23142;25412;54;;;
71;Algeria;1999;False;;22601;24654;100;;;
72;Algeria;1998;False;;21610;23615;100;;;
73;Algeria;1997;False;;20051;21489;75;;;
74;Algeria;1996;False;;19259;20654;130;;;
75;Algeria;1995;False;;18212;19714;193;;;
76;Algeria;1994;False;;17470;19888;166;;;
77;Algeria;1993;False;;16935;19415;353;;;
78;Algeria;1992;False;;16190;18286;199;;;
79;Algeria;1991;False;;15494;17345;293;;;
80;Algeria;1990;False;;14868;16104;135;;;
```

Comment: Start with standard descriptive statistics, e.g. plotting the data, and go from there.